# XCode 4 - What is this build directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, directory

I've set my custom build directory in XCode preferences.
The build directory works fine but what is this extra directory I see??

Along with a "**MyProject**" directory, there is another directory named something like...

"**MyProject-fcekgijdkfjiudjdhejfjshdjfhsjdk**"  or such.

What exactly is this?

Can I put this directory somewhere else so it does not mix with my "normal" build directory?
Can I change it's name?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the **DervicedData** Xcode generates now, instead of the build directory like Xcode 3.x.

This directory houses your product builds, debug information and a slew of other information that Xcode needs to link to your builds.

Your new **Debug / Release** directory is:

`MyProject-fcekgijdkfjiudjdhejfjshdjfhsjdk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`